# Jquery - How to draw line box (object) on image which can be dragged and removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to draw one more multiple line box on an image like this:

[image]

By giving a `(xAxis,yAxis,height,width,red/green)` then draw a box object on the image. 
The box objects can be removed and dragged. I know I can do it with `html canvas` for just draw box on it. However if I wanna manipulate(drag or remove) the box I think I have to create it as a javascript object. What's the good strategy to do so?

Answer (score 0):

use sketch.js [Use this link](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/lib/sketch.js)

To use Sketch.js in your project, just grab the latest sketch.js (or minified) from GitHub and include it in your project after jQuery.

Read the full tutorial for sketch js
[Read The Full Documentation](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/)

Comment: how to drag the draw object?